# strange behaviour of the locals() dictionary when using eval

Tags: python, eval

Please consider this code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import ParameterGrid

def conf1():
    return {"p1": [1,2], "p2": [4,5,6]}

def f(aa, bb, cc):
    c = locals()
    print("CONFIG, locals():")
    for k, v, in c.items():
        print(f"{k}: {v}")
    
    #>
    params = eval("conf1()")
    grid = ParameterGrid(params)
    #<

    d = {**c}
    
    print("CONF after eval")
    for k, v, in d.items():
        print(f"{k}: {v}")
    

f(1,2,3)
```

whose output is:

```
CONFIG, locals():
aa: 1
bb: 2
cc: 3
CONF after eval
aa: 1
bb: 2
cc: 3
c: {'aa': 1, 'bb': 2, 'cc': 3, 'c': {...}, 'k': 'cc', 'v': 3}
k: cc
v: 3
```

The function `f` creates a dictionary `c` with its local names, specifically the parameter it receives. Then a new dictionary is created by `eval("conf1()")`. After that, a new dictionary is created `d = {**c}`.

It seems that when `c = {**d}` is executed `d = locals()` is re-evaluated. Since at that point the local environment contains also `k`, `v` and `d` they end up in `d`. If I remove `eval` (the lines between `#>` and `#<`), I get what I expect, i.e., `c` and `d` contains the same items.

May be eval is not the reason, but I cannot really understand what is happening. I cannot find anything explaining this. Any help?

---

Since in the comments I read that `config` is a name of a mutable "locals()" I made this test:

```
def f(param1, param2):
    config = locals()
    print("1. config:")
    for k, v in config.items():
        print(f"- {k}: {v}")
        
    name =1 
    
    print("2. config:")
    for k, v in config.items():
        print(f"- {k}: {v}")
    
f(1, 2)
```

with output:

```
1. config:
- param2: 2
- param1: 1
2. config:
- param2: 2
- param1: 1
```

So it does not seem so mutable.

If one adds an `eval`:

```
def f(param1, param2):
    config = locals()
    print("1. config:")
    for k, v in config.items():
        print(f"- {k}: {v}")
        
    name = 1 
    eval("print()")
    
    print("2. config:")
    for k, v in config.items():
        print(f"- {k}: {v}")
    
f(1, 2)
```

again:

```
1. config:
- param2: 2
- param1: 1

2. config:
- param2: 2
- param1: 1
- name: 1
- v: 1
- k: param1
- config: {'param2': 2, 'param1': 1, 'name': 1, 'v': 1, 'k': 'param1', 'config': {...}}
```

---

After the comment of @juanpa.arrivillaga, I got it and was able to replicate without `eval()`:

```
def f(param1, param2):
    config = locals()
    print("1. config:")
    for k, v in config.items():
        print(f"- {k}: {v}")
        
    name = "hello"
    locals()
    
    print("2. config:")
    for k, v in config.items():
        print(f"- {k}: {v}")
    
f(1, 2)
```

with output:

```
1. config:
- param2: 2
- param1: 1
2. config:
- param2: 2
- param1: 1
- name: hello
- v: 1
- k: param1
- config: {'param2': 2, 'param1': 1, 'name': 'hello', 'v': 1, 'k': 'param1', 'config': {...}}
```

The documentation says:

> locals() Update and return a dictionary representing the current local
> symbol table. Free variables are returned by locals() when it is
> called in function blocks, but not in class blocks. Note that at the
> module level, locals() and globals() are the same dictionary.

I would have used "... return THE dictionary ..." rather than "a", but, anyway...

Thank you all.

---

For people hitting this page in the future. I started using `config=locals()` for keeping a config-like dictionary after reading examples on authoritative sources, but that assignment is not "correct" and leads to these strange behaviours, very difficult to spot in complex code.

A better way to use `locals()` to keep a config dictionary is `config = {**locals()}`:

```
def f(param1, param2):
    config = {**locals()}
    print("1. config:")
    for k, v in config.items():
        print(f"- {k}: {v}")
        
    name = "hello"
    locals()
    
    print("2. config:")
    for k, v in config.items():
        print(f"- {k}: {v}")
    
f(1, 2)
```

with the expected, normal behaviour, especially for people used to languages with variables instead of names:

```
1. config:
- param2: 2
- param1: 1
2. config:
- param2: 2
- param1: 1
```

And I agree with the author of the accepted answer: documentation should be closer to the actual semantics.

Comment: Are you sure that this output came from the exact code you show?  I don't see how it could include `c`, `k`, and `v`, without also including `params` and `grid`.

Comment: @jasonharper I just ran locally and got the same output as OP. Dropping the `eval()` line causes the behavior to disappear. I'm no Python expert so I'm assuming there is a reason for this behavior, but it sure does feel strange. I'm assuming it's the hook into `locals()` for the `c` variable and the mutability/mmutability of objects... just guessing.

Comment: `locals()` returns a mutable reference to the locals. It will sync bidirectionally to them

Comment: @mousetail Thank you for scratching that itch. Totally feels like confusion due to mutability. Maybe I'm getting better at python finally :)

Comment: @mousetail why `params` and `grid` are not printed then?

Comment: @mousetail no, `locals()` does not sync bidirectionally.

Comment: so, `eval` with no arguments will implicitly get `locals()`

Comment: `a = locals(); b = locals(); print(a is b)` gives `True`, as does `locals() is globals()` at the top-level. It looks like `locals()` always returns the same dictionary, though the docs don't require it to do so; the docs also don't say what happens with local variables declared after `locals()` is called. So all of this is just unspecified behaviour, I think; Python is allowed to do what it wants so long as it doesn't contradict anything the docs say specifically.

Comment: @kaya3 I agree, in this case if the doc said that locals() updates and returns always the same dictionary for the scope it would be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, `eval` will retreive the `locals()` implicitly. From the [docs for `eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval):

> If the `locals` dictionary is omitted it defaults to the `globals`
> dictionary. If both dictionaries are omitted, the expression is
> executed with the globals and locals in the environment where `eval()`
> is called.

And then from the docs on [`locals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals):

> Update and return a dictionary representing the current local symbol table.

So the precise behavior is not well defined. But it seems it is re-using the same dictionary, and updating it from the actual local symbol table each time it is called.

So:

```
>>> def foo():
...     l = locals()
...     print(l)
...     a = 42
...     print(l is locals())
...     print(l)
...     b = 11
...     print(l)
...
>>> foo()
{}
True
{'l': {...}, 'a': 42}
{'l': {...}, 'a': 42}
>>>
```